# Sending emails with SendGrid - Local ok , Remote no ok

Tags: sendgrid, azure-web-app-service

**Sending emails with SendGrid**

Works just fine on my local (code below)
No source control, just a straight WebDeploy of the same code to AzureWebsites yeilds the error below.  SendGrid support have no clue.

***Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:***

***[SocketException (0x271d): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions]***

*CodeScales.Http.HttpClient.Navigate(HttpRequest request, HttpBehavior httpBehavior) +772
   CodeScales.Http.HttpClient.Execute(HttpRequest request) +45
   SendGridMail.Transport.REST.Deliver(ISendGrid message) +115*

```
public bool SendEmail(string from, string to, string subject, string content)
  {
       var myMessage = SendGrid.GenerateInstance();
       // Setup the email properties.
       myMessage.From = new MailAddress(from);
       myMessage.AddTo(to);
       myMessage.Text = content;
       myMessage.Subject = subject;

       var username = "#####";
       var pswd = "#####";
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, pswd);
        // Get REST instance for sending email.
        var transportREST = REST.GetInstance(credentials);

        // Send the email.
        transportREST.Deliver(myMessage);

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This looks like some sort of Windows Azure bug rather than a SendGrid issue.  My two recommendations for fixing this are:

**1. Try using the SMTP API instead of the web API to send the email**

It could be that there's something wrong with outbound HTTP connections (this would really surprise me, but hey, it happens).

**2. Try using the code that Azure provides**

Azure has pretty good docs on how to use SendGrid, it might be worth taking a look at those and using some of their sample code.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/sendgrid-email-service/

**3. Contact Azure support**

They can look under the hood and see what it is that you're doing to cause the error.  If you do this, make sure you post back what they say here.

Comment: Thanks Swift.  

1. I tried a new azure website. With SMTP there’s no error, be still same error with REST.
Should we marked that as answered?? 

2. The code in from the reference in point 2 above is the same code.

3. AzureWebsites don't have support team I'm aware of.  If you could point in the right direction I'd be grateful.

Comment: Glad you got it resolved.  You can find windows azure support here: https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?gprid=14928&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn&ln=en-us

Comment: I had exactly the same issue and error when using REST - changing to SMTP has fixed the problem. Looks like Web API email sending is not properly supported in Azure. Good job this post was only closed and not deleted as I am a future visitor that it has helped :)

Comment: Looks like there is a patch for this issue coming soon.